# LineItems not showing in CMS

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, php, order

I'm scratching my head. My orders are shown perfectly except for one product. I have no idea why so I looked at the Order object before saving and I can't seem to figure out why he won't show the lineitems in the CMS.

This is my object:

```
{
    "number": "17092020135106598",
    "reference": "They Were Soldiers",
    "couponCode": null,
    "isCompleted": true,
    "dateOrdered": {
        "date": "17/09/2020",
        "time": "13:53"
    },
    "datePaid": {
        "date": "17/09/2020",
        "time": "13:53"
    },
    "dateAuthorized": null,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "gatewayId": 1,
    "lastIp": "81.82.213.80",
    "message": null,
    "returnUrl": null,
    "cancelUrl": null,
    "orderStatusId": "1",
    "orderLanguage": "en-BE",
    "origin": "web",
    "billingAddressId": null,
    "shippingAddressId": null,
    "makePrimaryShippingAddress": null,
    "makePrimaryBillingAddress": null,
    "shippingSameAsBilling": null,
    "billingSameAsShipping": null,
    "estimatedBillingAddressId": null,
    "estimatedShippingAddressId": null,
    "estimatedBillingSameAsShipping": null,
    "shippingMethodHandle": "freeShipping",
    "customerId": 191,
    "registerUserOnOrderComplete": null,
    "paymentSourceId": null,
    "storedTotalPrice": null,
    "storedTotalPaid": null,
    "storedItemTotal": null,
    "storedTotalShippingCost": null,
    "storedTotalDiscount": null,
    "storedTotalTax": null,
    "storedTotalTaxIncluded": null,
    "id": 614,
    "tempId": null,
    "draftId": null,
    "revisionId": null,
    "uid": "9ffedad4-5318-4b66-95db-f0f0f3c3418a",
    "fieldLayoutId": 1,
    "contentId": "613",
    "enabled": true,
    "archived": false,
    "siteId": "1",
    "title": null,
    "slug": null,
    "uri": null,
    "dateCreated": {
        "date": "17/09/2020",
        "time": "13:53"
    },
    "dateUpdated": {
        "date": "17/09/2020",
        "time": "13:53"
    },
    "dateDeleted": null,
    "trashed": false,
    "propagateAll": true,
    "newSiteIds": [],
    "resaving": false,
    "duplicateOf": null,
    "previewing": false,
    "hardDelete": false,
    "ref": null,
    "status": "enabled",
    "structureId": null,
    "url": null,
    "adjustmentSubtotal": 0,
    "adjustmentsTotal": 0,
    "paymentCurrency": "EUR",
    "email": "xx@xxxxx.xx",
    "isPaid": false,
    "itemSubtotal": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "itemTotal": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "id": 247,
            "description": "They Were Soldiers - 25mm Miniatures",
            "price": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
            "saleAmount": 0,
            "salePrice": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
            "weight": 0,
            "length": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "width": 0,
            "qty": 1,
            "sku": "TWSKS2021",
            "note": "",
            "privateNote": null,
            "purchasableId": "571",
            "orderId": 614,
            "lineItemStatusId": null,
            "taxCategoryId": 1,
            "shippingCategoryId": 1,
            "dateCreated": "2020-09-17T13:53:07+02:00",
            "adjustments": [],
            "options": [],
            "optionsSignature": "d751713988987e9331980363e24189ce",
            "onSale": false,
            "total": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
            "priceAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
            "saleAmountAsCurrency": 0,
            "salePriceAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
            "subtotalAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
            "totalAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
            "subtotal": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125
        }
    ],
    "orderAdjustments": [],
    "outstandingBalance": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "paidStatus": "unpaid",
    "recalculationMode": "none",
    "shortNumber": "1709202",
    "totalPaid": 0,
    "total": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "totalPrice": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "totalQty": 1,
    "totalSaleAmount": 0,
    "totalTaxablePrice": 98.2000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125,
    "totalWeight": 0,
    "adjustmentSubtotalAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "adjustmentsTotalAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "itemSubtotalAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "itemTotalAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "outstandingBalanceAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "totalPaidAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "totalAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "totalPriceAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "totalSaleAmountAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "totalTaxablePriceAsCurrency": "98,20 €",
    "totalTaxAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "totalTaxIncludedAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "totalShippingCostAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "totalDiscountAsCurrency": "0 €",
    "paidStatusHtml": "<span class=\"commerceStatusLabel\"><span class=\"status red\"></span> Unpaid</span>",
    "customerLinkHtml": "",
    "orderStatusHtml": "<span class=\"commerceStatusLabel\"><span class=\"status yellow\"></span> New</span>"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! The problem was that somehow, with that product, there was an issue with setting the status of the order to 'Paid'. Once I got that working, I saw the lineitems in my order.